# jpeg don't pass on mac

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

android 5,1 on soyes 6,1, photos on SD card (FAT32), not on the phone storage;
when connected the jpeg don't open on mac's aperçu, announce corrupted (missing meta dates); on the phone (android) it appears normally.
what's wrong ?

Comment: Try sending the image by e-mail to yourself and then open it on your mac. Not sure why it would fix it, but it might...

Comment: thanks for your idea, already tried without success...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved...:
I started directly using the phone choosing SD for memory, including of course photos.
And that problem came out. Untill I changed tothe phone memory, then photos are normally available on mac. Going back then using again SD as memory, the problem is gone, photos available also on mac. It looks like it was necessary to start photographing at leaast once with phone memory, BEFORE switching to SD memory. Now it works.
Hope this will be usefull to other soyes users...
Bertrand Chevalley

Comment: Sounds strange (I think there was probably _something else_ going on here that prevented the photos from the SD card working initially), but glad you got it working!